# JQuery variable as ID results in Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#cell32'

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I have the following code:

```
var currentRow = this.id.charAt(4);
var testRow = Number(currentRow) - 1;
var testCellId = "'#cell" + currentRow + testRow +"'";
var testCell = $(testCellId).get(0);
```

It results in the error:
"Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#cell32'"

If I use the variable value, `#cell32`, instead of the variable:

```
var testCell = $('#cell32').get(0);
```

There is no error.

I have also checked with console.log(testCellId) and the variable does contain the correct value.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra set of quotes in there.
Your jQuery selector should be just `#cell32`, not `'#cell32'`.

So:

```
var testCellId = "#cell" + currentRow + testRow;
```

It appears you've mistaken the `"` and/or `'` characters that surround a *string literal* as being part of the actual string that they describe, but they're not; they just introduce or *delimit* it.

Comment: Sorry - forgot to accept the answer! It's checked now :-)